# Arduino-esp32 GATT Server passiv scanning

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm building a iOS app that needs to scan for devices in the background. According to the CoreBluetooth documentation, the device needs to support passive scanning.
In other words the ADV_IND needs to advertise with the service uuid and after that respond with the additional advertising data.
Is it possible to implement this behaviour with the Arduino-esp32 library?

I already tried setting `pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);` but then iOS does not recognise the esp32 at all.

Thanks for your help.